# Where does C function's TAN return its value in 64-bit GCC?

Tags: gcc, assembly, return, 64-bit

I am linking my assembly function with GCC on linux 64-bit. The library I use is TAN from math.h. I link it with;

```
gcc -s prog.o -o prog -lm
```

The program works but the return value is 0.0000000 (for 3.4 radian). I use extrn in my assembly code;

```
extrn tan
extrn printf
```

I use xmm0 to pass the argument (in radian) to the TAN function. Now I am not sure which register is used to return the value from TAN. Is it xmm0, st0 or in RAX? I can't find a decent reference on this.

Comment: It is `xmm0`. The reference is the [x86-64 abi documentation](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf), not sure why you couldn't find it.

Comment: Ok its xmm0 then. TBH, I can't read AT&T. It breaks my heart to see such an important reference is written in AT&T. LOL. Thanks.

Comment: It's about a 5 minute effort to learn at&t. Anyway, for the part where it says `xmm0` is used to return values, you don't even need that much.

Comment: I hit the 'x' button of the ABI page once I found out it was in at&t. I never return since. LOL

Comment: All I hear is "I deliberately chose ignore relevant authoritative documentation."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my gcc, it's xmm0.

Here's a C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {

  double x = tan(M_PI/4.0);
  // RESULT: x=1.000000
  printf ("x=%f\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

And here's the corresponding "gcc -S":

```
.Ltext0:
        .section        .rodata
.LC1:
        .string "x=%f\n"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
        .file 1 "x.cpp"
        .loc 1 4 0
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $32, %rsp
.LBB2:
        .loc 1 6 0
        movabsq $4607182418800017407, %rax
        movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
        .loc 1 8 0
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
        movsd   -24(%rbp), %xmm0
        movl    $.LC1, %edi
        movl    $1, %eax
        call    printf
        .loc 1 9 0
        movl    $0, %eax
.LBE2:
        .loc 1 10 0
        leave
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: There is not a call to `tan()` anywhere, nor any floating-point instructions in that assembly listing. Note that [tan(pi/4) = 1.0](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=tan(pi%20%2F%204)). The compiler recognized this, and performed the calculation at *compile time*. If you look at the code you've posted, you see `movabsq $4607182418800017407, %rax`. Interpreting that value as a `double`, we see that it is ~`1.0`.  The mov into `xmm0` is setting up for the call to `printf` - the first floating-point argument is passed in `xmm0`.